# Can Apple's color picker be opened from anywhere?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, color-picker

Is it possible to open the native color picker from anywhere in the OS, perhaps through Terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the AppleScript Editor and create a new script with `choose color` inside, then run  or export the script as Application.

Answer (score 1):

Sure can.  You create an Apple Script, save it as an application, and you're done.
A walk through is right [here](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/category-utilities.php)